# Removing @ from an e:p combination except the one in email domain

Tags: regex

I need to remove "@" character from the Password section of an e;p combination with a regex command, but the "@" in the email remains intact.

The "@" could be anywhere or with any repetition time (2 or more instances) in the Password section. What can be the regex command?

e.g;

```
sddw@we.com:@defe@wefe@fee
```

turns into;

```
sddw@we.com:defewefefee
```

Comment: What pattern did you come up with? Did you try something?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij :*@ select all @, but I need to deselect the one in email

Comment: This regex seems to work for the example given `@(?!.+\..+:)`. See if it is useful. Btw, I am a RegEx novice and learner.

Comment: You could just split the string in two by `:` sign and then remove all `@` characters in the second part

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
 ^([^\r\n:]+:)\s*|([^\r\n@]+)|@
```

and a replacement of `$1$2` might be an option to explore.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fn9rDL/1/)

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fn9rDL/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/fn9rDL/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.